# How to embed a $\mathbb{P}^1$-fibration into a suitable projective bundle?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Here is my question:

> Let $f:W\to X$ be a smooth $\mathbb{P}^1$-fibration of smooth projective varieties over $\mathbb{C}$ where $\rho(X)=1$ and $X$ is Fano. How can we get a a vector bundle $\mathscr{E}$ of rank $3$ such that $f$ is just the composition of an embedding $W\subset\mathbb{P}_X(\mathscr{E})\to X$ and satisfies that $W\in|2\eta|$ as a divisor where $\eta$ be the tautological divisor and $\mathscr{E}\cong\mathscr{E}^{\vee}$?

I have no idea about this... Maybe this is related to the theory of Brauer-Severi schemes?

Besides, it there some general method to solve the following question?

> Let $f:W\to X$ be a smooth $\mathbb{P}^r$-fibration, that is, $f$ is a smooth morphism and all its fiber is $\mathbb{P}^r$. Let $W,X$ are smooth projective varieties over $\mathbb{C}$. Is there exists a vector bundle $\mathscr{E}$ of rank $R\geq r+1$ such that $f$ is just the composition of an embedding $W\subset\mathbb{P}_X(\mathscr{E})\to X$?

It is well-known that if there is a section of $f$, then $f$ is just of form $\mathbb{P}_X(\mathscr{E})$. Maybe we need some descent theory since this is a etale local projective-bundle?

---

Thank you for your any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard approach is to define
$$
\mathcal{E} := f_*(\omega_{W/X}^{-1})
$$
(you may need to dualize this bundle, depending on your convention about projectivizations). It is not true in general that $\mathcal{E}$ is self-dual. In general,
$$
\mathcal{E}^\vee \cong \mathcal{E} \otimes \mathcal{L},
$$
where $\mathcal{L}$ may be not a square.

However, if the Picard group of $X$ is cyclic, taking the determinants of the above isomorphism, one gets
$$
(\det(\mathcal{E})^\vee)^{\otimes 2} \cong \mathcal{L}^{\otimes 3},
$$
which implies that $\mathcal{L}$ is a square. So, if $\mathcal{L} \cong \mathcal{M}^{\otimes 2}$, one has
$$
(\mathcal{E} \otimes \mathcal{M})^\vee \cong
\mathcal{E} \otimes \mathcal{M},
$$
and therefore $W \subset \mathbb{P}(\mathcal{E} \otimes \mathcal{M})$ is a divisor of type $2\eta$.

In higher dimensions you can define $\mathcal{E}$ by the same formula, and then you will have an embedding of $W$ into $\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{E})$ which is the Veronese embedding of degree $r + 1$ in each fiber.

Comment: Thanks! This is the first step in the Proposition 4.4 in "https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.04579" which claim that $\mathscr{E}$ is self-dual.

Comment: If the Picard group of the base is cyclic, one can, indeed, modify $\mathcal{E}$ so that it becomes self-dual. I added the details to the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed and patient answer! But there is still one step I don't understand. In our case we have $\mathscr{E}^{\vee}\cong R^1f_*(\omega_{W/X}^{\otimes 2})$, but why $\mathscr{E}^{\vee}\cong \mathscr{E}\otimes\mathscr{L}$ for some line bundle $\mathscr{L}$?

Comment: As $W \subset \mathbb{P}(\mathcal{E})$ is a conic in each fiber, so it is a divisor of relative degree 2, hence it is given by a global section of a line bundle that can be written as $$\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{E})/X}(2) \otimes f^*\mathcal{L}^\vee$$ for some line bundle $\mathcal{L}$ on $X$. Its global section, therefore, is a section of $\mathrm{Sym}^2\mathcal{E}^\vee \otimes \mathcal{L}^\vee$, i.e., a morphism $\mathcal{E} \otimes \mathcal{L} \to \mathcal{E}^\vee$. Since all the conics are nondegenerate, this morphism is an isomorphism.

Comment: Thank you very much!